# Deleting item from list causes to delete from ancestor

Tags: python-3.x, list

I am building a for loop but i face a strange behavior,  like i need to delete items from list while loop but later get the full list again. but when i delete the item, it deletes from ancestor also. simple example for the issue.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = a
b.remove(3)
print(a,b)
```

output

```
[1, 2, 4, 5] [1, 2, 4, 5]
```

But what i expected output as:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] [1, 2, 4, 5]
```

i couldn't figure out how to correctly reference so that ancestor will not be effected.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Use : to copy, see the duplicate for detail.

Comment: Thanks, i search but couldn't find unfortunately.